# Why is my cshtml being broken by partial tags within an if statement block?

Tags: c#, razor, partial-views

Probably quite simple, but I'm new to C# and Razor, and I'm having trouble finding an answer.

I have multiple links across my project that I want to display through partials. 95% of them are absolutely fine. However one sits within an @if block. With this one VSCode throws an absolute fit with the html and fails to recognise any opening/closing tags on either side of it.

E.g.

```
@if (x != 1)
{
   <div class="pleasework">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah <partial name="_PartialLink" /><strong>What is wrong with you?</strong></a></p>
   </div>
}
```

Where the partial is:

`<a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">`

...causes the opening `<p>` tag to complain that it isn't being closed. The closing `</p>` claims it was never opened, and finally the `</` of the closing `</a>` displays as text/variable rather than as a tag.

EDIT WITH MY SOLUTION:

Open partials were identified as bad practice so looked at other routes. Instead created a model string in the partial file:

```
@model string

<a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">@Model</a>
```

and then in the cshtml...

```
@if (x != 1)
{
   <div class="pleasework">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah <strong><partial name="_PartialLink" Model=@("What is wrong with you?")></partial></strong></p>
   </div>
}
```

I'm new to posting here so I don't know what happens with this thread. Deleting it feels like it wastes the learning exercise and the assisting comments.

Comment: Partials are meant to include self contained bits of Razor templating: they're not meant to contain unclosed elements.  If you want to have a partial that contains a hyperlink that has varying display text, then you need to pass your display text into the partial.

Comment: That may end up being the final word on the matter, but do you have any idea why it works everywhere apart from the if block? Or a fitting replacement given the content enclosed within the anchor tags varies?